# ASP.NET MVC 3 - How to Reuse Solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What's the best way to structure the base functionality of an ASP.NET MVC 3 solution so it can be reused in subsequent solutions? For example, I'm going to develop a basic skeleton MVC app with user registration using email verification, enhanced users/right/roles, blogging with comments, and a forum. I understand maintaining the business logic in class libraries but how about the controllers and views? Do I basically have to just copy and paste my base solution to create each of my new solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Creating a Custom ASP.NET MVC Project Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx)
- [templify](http://opensource.endjin.com/templify/)

[image]